# Is it a noun clause or phrase when the nominal entity is modified by a determiner?

Tags: phrases, nouns, clauses, subordinate-clauses

From my textbook, A noun phrase is headed by a noun. Modifiers include articles, adjectives and demonstratives. Qualifiers include prepositional phrases and relative/adjectival clauses.

Given the following:

Your bag is in **your locker**

What is the grammatical name? I know that its grammatical/syntactic function is the complement of the preposition .

The problem is that I suspect it is a noun clause because "your" is neither an article, adjective nor a demonstrative. It is a determiner. Also, a noun clause can be perform every function that a noun phrase can, or so I think.

Comment: I don't follow you. "Your locker" is simply a noun phrase with the noun "locker" as head and the genitive pronoun "your" as determiner. The noun phrase is object of the preposition "in".

Comment: @BillJ thank you, I guess that definition of a noun phrase is still incomplete. The writer probably assumed some knowledge from the reader which I do not have. Can you help with the difference between a noun phrase and noun clause, one that helps me understand your answer rather than taking it as it is

Comment: A noun phrase is a type of phrase (one or more words) whose head word is a noun. By contrast, a clause has a subject and predicate, the latter consisting of a verb phrase whose head word is a verb.

Comment: It's simpler to look at *your* as a type of adjective.

Comment: @Alphonsus Incidentally, there is no such thing as a noun clause. The classification of finite subordinate clauses is based on their internal form rather than spurious analogies with the parts of speech. .

Comment: @BillJ thank you. Can you write it as an answer so that I can accept it. I am new to the community and cannot upvote your answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Your bag is in* [*your locker*].

"Your locker" is not a clause but a noun phrase with the noun "locker" as head and the genitive pronoun "your" as determiner. Its function is that of object of the preposition "in".

A noun phrase is a type of phrase consisting of one or more words whose head word is a noun.

By contrast, a clause has a subject-predicate structure; the latter component consisting of a verb phrase whose head word is a verb.

Incidentally, there is no such thing as a noun clause. The classification of finite subordinate clauses is based on their internal form rather than spurious analogies with the parts of speech.

Comment: It’s not my terminology, but in old-fashioned non-professional materials purporting to teach basic English grammar, the term *noun clause* is used to mean any clause (be it finite or nonfinite) serving as another clause’s subject, object, or complement, or as an appositive to another NP, or as the object of a preposition, etc. Often as not these texts also contain strange terms like *noun adjectives* to go with their *noun clauses*, *adjective nouns* for something else again, and a complete confusion over “gerunds”. I would never recommend such texts, but often these are all a student knows.

Comment: Many traditions of grammar terminology exist besides the one in CGEL. One quite reasonable one if noting the use of a clause. _Adjective clauses_ modify nouns; they include relative clauses and NP complements. _Adverb clauses_, often headed by subordinators, mostly modify clauses or phrases. And _noun clauses_ like _that_ complements, embedded questions, infinitives, or gerunds, serve as nouns (typically subject or object) in some higher clause. To refuse to use any such terms is reasonable; to correct other's use is not

Comment: The term 'noun clause' is a misnomer. Such clauses function primarily as complement, not noun, which is not a function but a word category (POS). Consider "The suggestion **that they cheated** was quite outrageous", where the subordinate clause is traditionally classified as a noun clause and yet it is not replaceable by a noun. Similarly, the subordinate clause in "They appointed Ed, **which turned out to be a bad mistake**" is traditionally called an adjective clause, but it could not be replaced by an adjective. They are, respectively, a declarative content clause and a relative clause.